# How to Pivot the result of an aggregated series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a series called 'results' I created with a

```
groupby
```

on 2 columns 'dt' and 'vc', summing a third numeric column 'numcol'.

The result looks like this:

```
dt     vc       
abc    ghi       3.2
       jkl      44.1
       mmm      15.2
xyz    def      11.3
       hhh       8.2
       jjj       4.4
```

Wanting to do a pivot, I create a dataframe:

```
resultsdf = results.to_frame()
```

It looks like this :

```
                   numcol
dt    vc       
abc   ghi          3.2
      jkl         44.1
[....]
```

How to pivot resultsdf such that the index is dt, the columns are vc, and the values of the cells are numcol?

I had trouble resetting index of this structure and then setting to dt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `unstack` on `results` directly with `level=1`(vc):

```
results.unstack(level=1)
```

[image]

Or more explicitly:

```
results.unstack("vc")
```

Comment: or using the last index level by default `results.unstack()`